# why cross join is not working as Cartesian Production with jsonb_array_elements in Postgresql v9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my demo sql.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vk8sCioCh1RstjSWXsZnWr/2

I want to flatten the json array and mapping to its parent.

```
select * from Orders
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(data->'products') as product_item;
```

This sql works as I want but I don't know why it works.
Why I can cross join without specifying table?
<s>Is the db-fiddle error</s>   or how postgresql works internally ? It also works on my laptop.

Thanks.

Comment: You do have a table - the one returned by `jsonb_array_elements()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However like left join, I need to explicitly declare such as `select * from table1 left join table2`. Why cross join can work not only in this way ? I didn't find any clue in the doc.

Comment: You could also do `from table1 left join lateral jsonb_array_elements(...) on ...`

Comment: another question is cross join should be N * M ?